# Android Edit text disabling when using another

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two edit text and i want to disable one of them when i set an input in the other.I used TextWatcher like below :

```
     private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private View view;
    public MyTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view=view;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.cin:
            if(mEdCin.getText().toString()!=null){
            mEdPassport.setKeyListener(null);
            mEdPassport.setFocusable(false);
        }
        else if(mEdCin.getText().toString()==null) {
                mEdPassport.setFocusable(true);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.passport:

            if(mEdPassport.getText().toString()!=null){
            mEdCin.setKeyListener(null);
            mEdCin.setFocusable(false);
        }
            break;
    }

    }
```

but when i clear the edit text i was using, the other still disable .
how i can set it enable if the i clear the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `EditText` value is empty using `isEmpty()` method, try it like this

```
if(firstEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
   secondEditText.setEnabled(true);  
   //...  
} else {
   secondEditText.setEnabled(false);    
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding :

```
    edittext.setFocusable(false);
    edittext.setEnabled(false);
    edittext.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: Up to my knowledge  edittext.setEnabled(false); is enough for the desired output. Make sure afterTextChanged() method invoked when you clear the edit text value